# standard array changed to associative array breaks JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a script that I've used to check inputs if they are the same as values from array and if there are any repetitions

```
 echo '<input class="champion" type="text" list="champions" placeholder="Champion '.$i.'" name="champno[]" required autofocus><br/>
                        <datalist id="champions"></datalist>';
var config = {
              fillAll: true
            };

            document.forms["second_form"].oninput = function(e) {
              var champion = this["champno[]"];

              //Force into array
              if (champion[0] === undefined)
                champion = [this["champno[]"]];

              var reached = {
                valid: 0,
                unique: 0
              };

              var inputs = [].map.call(champion, function(n) {
                return n.value
              }).filter(function(n) {
                return n.length
              });

              var valid = [].every.call(champion, function(n, i) {
                n.setCustomValidity("");
                if (config.fillAll) return (reached.valid = i, champions.indexOf(n.value) > -1);
                else return n.value ? (
                  reached.valid = i,
                  champions.indexOf(n.value) > -1
                ) : true;
              });

              var unique = inputs.slice(0).sort().every(function(n, i, a) {
                reached.unique = inputs.lastIndexOf(n);
                return n != a[i - 1];
              });

              //Check for valid champions
              if (!valid) {
                champion[reached.valid].setCustomValidity("This is not a valid champion, please correct this field and resubmit.")
              }

              //Check for duplicates
              if (!unique) {
                champion[reached.unique].setCustomValidity("This champion has already been entered.")
              }

              this.checkValidity();
            };
```

I changed my array from this:

```
var champions = [
            "Aatrox", "Ahri", "Akali"
        ];
```

To this:

```
var champions = {

    "Aatrox":["Blood Well","Dark Flight", "Blood Thirst / Blood Price", "Blades of Torment", "Massacre"],
    "Ahri":["Essence Theft","Orb of Deception", "Fox-Fire", "Charm", "Spirit Rush"],
    "Akali":["Twin Disciplines", "Mark of the Assassin", "Twilight Shroud", "Crescent Slash", "Shadow Dance"]
    };
```

Which breaks the script with error: 'champions.indexOf is not a function' and I'm not really sure how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

`.indexOf` is part of the Array prototype, and isn't available to object literals. If all you are doing is a check to see if the key exists, you can do it like this:

`if( champions[n.value] ) ...`

Or:

`champions.hasOwnProperty(n.value)`

Comment: It fixed most of my problem. The code is supposed to check if input is the same as sth from the Array so user is forced to type Aatrox not for example aaaatrox this doesn't work but checking for duplicates works fine

Comment: @Higeath often times when attempting to check for that type of thing you'll 'normalize' both the input and the value being checked against. Remove white space, reduce to all lowercase, and in extreme cases do a character comparison to identify if input is 'close enough'.

Comment: it worked just fine with regular array so i could assume its still something with the code

Comment: @Higeath I'd have to know where the code isn't working, what the expected results would be compared to what the results are now. If it's easier, why don't you simply recreate the old array from the keys of the object and keep all the code the same? You can then use the array items to reference the object values.